# Convenient and readable way of removing an element from std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I need to erase/remove an element from a `std::vector`.

I know that this can be done with `myvector.erase(myvector.begin() + index)` but this looks ugly to me.

Something like `myvector.removeindex(index)` would be so much more readable.

Do they plan something like that in C++20 or in C++23 ?

Comment: No, they do not. Removal by index is trivial to do (as you've done) and isn't important enough to need a special function for it. That you find it ugly is not a compelling reason to add a function to the standard library.

Comment: Maybe get used to working with iterators instead of index?

Comment: Unless you directly get a user input specifying the index, in all other cases it's more natural (consistent w/ the design of c++) to use iterators. Also consider using `std::erase` and `std::erase_if` if you need to remove more than one elements.

Comment: There is an erase/remove idiom, but it's better suited to multiple elements, usually that pass/fail some condition. If you just need to remove a single element, I don't see what's so unreadable about a find/erase combo.

Comment: @sweenish No need for erase/remove since C++20. Just use `std::erase` and `std::erase_if`.

Comment: Maybe a helper lambda to the rescue? `auto remove_index{ [&myvector](std::size_t index) { myvector.erase(myvector.begin() + index); } };`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Didn't realize those were added. Good to know!

Answer (score 5):

Both C++20 and C++23 are finished, so there are no "plans" to do anything in them. And there are no proposals for C++26 to add this function.

Nor is there a likelihood that such a trivial proposal would be accepted. Containers are meant to use iterator-based interfaces. Converting an index into an iterator for a random access container is pretty trivial, so there is no compelling reason to create a specialized function.

But if you really want, you can make your own free function that, through concepts, works on any random access range that you can erase from:

```
template<std::ranges::random_access_range T>
  requires requires(T &t) {t.erase(std::ranges::begin(t));}
constexpr auto remove_index(T &t, std::ranges::range_difference_t<T> ix)
{
  return t.erase(std::ranges::begin(t) + ix);
}
```

Comment: Could add an extra flavor by inscribing `noexcept(noexcept(t.erase(std::ranges::begin(t) + ix)))`.

Comment: @user7860670: The various container `erase` functions have no `noexcept` specifications, so this would basically always be `noexcept(false)`.